# mkfs complain about disk is apparently in use by the system

Tags: rhel, ps, lsof, xfs, mkfs

on our rhel server we want to re-create ext4 filesystem as

```
[root@worker ~]# mkfs.ext4  -j -m 0 /dev/sdd -F
mke2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
/dev/sdd is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!
[root@worker ~]# lsof /dev/sdd
```

as above even we use `-F` , the mkfs complain about  `/dev/sdd` is apparently in use by the system

and lsof not show any process

any hint how to release the disk ?

```
lsblk /dev/sdd
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdd    8:48   0  20G  0 disk
```

Comment: Is it mounted? Are you sure you want to use `mkfs.ext4` given that you mention re-creating an XFS file system?

Comment: the disk isnt mount to folder for sure

Comment: sorry its typo its ext4 my mistake

Comment: What does `lsblk /dev/sdd` show?

Comment: I update the question

Comment: Is the disk partitioned, and if so, is any of the partitions still in use/mounted? Or is this device just a single access path to a multipathed disk, in which case it might be held by the dm-multipath subsystem, and you should be using the appropriate multipathed device instead? Or is it encrypted or part of a software RAID set?

Comment: If the disk is mentioned in the output of "dmsetup ls --tree -o blkdevname", it's currently used by some multipath/soft-RAID/crypt/LVM setup.

Comment: Because you add `rhel` tag I want to ask if disk is not part of lvm?

Comment: yes this disk isn't part of lvm

Comment: Are you sure you don't actually want to format `/dev/sddn` (with n= 1,2,...) ?

Comment: I had this problem with a USB flash drive. Unplugging and plugging it back in worked for me. Drive ID changed from sdf to sdg.